# Terminology for how bendable an object is and what affects the bendable-ness of an object

Tags: terminology, material-science, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I was wondering what the term is for how bendable an object is. Also, does this feature vary depending on the thickness of the object? Say, for example, I want to know how bendable a ruler is. Does the thickness affect the bendable-ness of the ruler?

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to an object the measure of the property you look for is the bending stiffness. The bending stiffness is proportional to the axial Young Modulus and to the cross sectional moment of inertia (a function of the thickness). The so-called flexural Young modulus is a property of the material and not of the beam geometric parameters.

Comment: The term I am used to is ["Flexural Rigidity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexural_rigidity) and not flexural Young's modulus.

Comment: The flexural rigidity is exactly the bending stiffness.

Comment: The exact term is then "Elastic Modulus" or "Youngs Modulus" which refers to the elastic response of normal stress (as opposed to shear stress), and not necessarily related to a "flexural" response.

Comment: The elastic modulus is the slope of the stress-strain relation in the linear region. It is not associated to the geometry of the beam; therefore it is not a complete stiffness measure.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the property referred to as the *flexural modulus*, but I've also read it often does not vary significantly from the standard [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus). This property is inherent to the material, but if you ask, "How far does the material of a given length and thickness bend given a certain applied force," then the answer is that the object will bend more the longer and skinnier it is. This property can be determined with a [three-point test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-point_flexural_test).